# having problems clearing a directory and uploading files via a batch file

Tags: ftp, batch-file, filezilla, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running Filezilla-Server on a Windows 2012R2 Standard server. I am attempting to ftp in and send files from another Windows 2012R2 Standard server.

I am running this batch file:

```
@echo off
cls
echo open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx> ftpcmd.dat
echo user xxxxxxxxx>> ftpcmd.dat
echo xxxxxxxx>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd %1zip>> ftpcmd.dat
echo pwd>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mdelete *>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mkdir %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mput *.*>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
@echo on
ftp -i -n -s:ftpcmd.dat
```

This is the results when I run it:

```
C:\backup>ftp -i -n -s:ftpcmd.dat
ftp> open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.44 beta
220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
ftp> user xxxxxxxxx
331 Password required for xxxxxxxxx

230 Logged on
ftp> bin
200 Type set to I
ftp> lcd ppsvm
Local directory now C:\backup\ppsvm.
ftp> lcd ppsvmzip
Local directory now C:\backup\ppsvm\ppsvmzip.
ftp> pwd
257 "/" is current directory.
ftp> mdelete *
_   <-- it just sticks here and goes nowhere
```

**As you can see from the ^ above it stops at mdelete and doesn't do anything else.**

I checked the Filezilla-Server log and it shows this:

```
8:28:21 AM - (not logged in)> Connected, sending welcome message...
8:28:21 AM - (not logged in)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.44 beta
8:28:21 AM - (not logged in)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
8:28:21 AM - (not logged in)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
8:28:21 AM - (not logged in)> USER xxxxxxxxxxxxx
8:28:21 AM - (not logged in)> 331 Password required for xxxxxxxxxxxxx
8:28:21 AM - (not logged in)> PASS ****************
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> 230 Logged on
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> TYPE I
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> 200 Type set to I
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> XPWD
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> 257 "/" is current directory.
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> TYPE A
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> 200 Type set to A
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> PORT xxx,xxx,xxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> 200 Port command successful
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> NLST *
8:28:21 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/*"
8:28:32 AM - xxxxxxxxxxxxx> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/*"
```

I have the Filezilla-Server added to my firewall settings:

[image]

I even turned off the Firewall to verify it was not interfering so I don't believe it is the firewall.

I'm at a loss as to what is going on. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: when you say that you turned off firewall, do you mean **on both** machines? Active FTP is bi-directional (control conn goes client->srv, data connection srv ->client)

Comment: I'll turn if off on both and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @wmz That was it. I disabled the firewall and it worked without issue. If you post this as your answer I'll give you credit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active FTP is bi-directional (control conn goes client->srv, data connection srv ->client)  so it needs to allow incoming connections on specific ports for server **and** client.

Here is a quote from [FileZilla wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration) (which has a nice explanation of ftp internals)

> What distinguishes FTP from most other protocols is the use of
>   secondary connections for file transfers. When you connect to an FTP
>   server, you are actually making two connections. First, the so-called
>   control connection is established, over which FTP commands and their
>   replies are transferred. Then, in order to transfer a file or a
>   directory listing, the client sends a particular command over the
>   control connection to establish the data connection.

(...)

> In active mode, the client opens a socket on the local machine and
>   tells its address to the server using the PORT command. Once the
>   client issues a command to transfer a file or listing, the server will
>   connect to the address provided by the client.

You will also find information on firewall config for client and server in the wiki.

Comment: I added c:\windows\systems32\ftp.exe to the firewall and that worked. Thank you for your help!